# create a pull request for a single commit made on a fork of a fork on github

Tags: github, pull-request

So,

I have the following situation. There is the original repo on github: `Repo A`. Also there is a fork that contained some great additions to that repo: `Repo B`.

So I forked Repo B and added some nice code. I created a pull request and the owner of `Repo B` asked me to make a pull request directly to `Repo A` instead.

The situation looks like this now:

```
Repo A (original)
     |
     ▼
Repo B (some great features)
     |
     ▼
Repo C (my fork, has some changes that need to go to Repo A directly)
```

But I cannot make a pull request directly to `Repo A` that hold only my changes. The reason is that there are several other changes (made to `Repo B`) that my change was based on. What I get when I create a pull request at the moment is all the changes made to `Repo B` plus the change I made to `Repo C`.

On github, I cannot make a second fork of a project since the name is already used.

So, what should I do now? Is there a command line work around to get this solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add Repository A as a remote to your local repository:

```
git remote add repo-a <url>
git fetch repo-a
```

Create your own branch based on the branch you should open a pull request against. This is conventionally `master`, but check the `README` or `CONTRIBUTING` files for instructions.

```
git checkout -b my-feature repo-a/master
```

Now, you're on a branch called `my-feature` (name this for what you've done). Use `cherry-pick` to get the commit you made onto this branch where `<hash>` is the hash of your commit:

```
git cherry-pick <hash>
```

You now have a local branch ready for a pull request. Push that branch to your fork to publish it (assuming `origin` is the name of the remote for your fork):

```
git push origin my-feature
```

You can now open a pull request from `my-feature` on your fork to `master` in Repository A.

Comment: Warning: this procedure works well in most regards, except it creates `my-feature` with `repo-a/master` as its upstream, which can lead to problems, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/q/71209460/3216427  It's better to use `git checkout repo-a/master; git checkout -b my-feature` and set the upstream later with `git push -u origin my-feature`, since you'll be pushing to your own fork only, and using a PR to submit the changes to `repo-a`.

Comment: Or [use --no-track when you create the branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71210720/3216427) .