# Updates were rejected error when pushing to new remote branch

Tags: git, github

I have forked a github repository and by now my fork is several commits ahead. I now want to provide *one* of these commits as a PR to the original repository.

Following [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21527233/create-a-pull-request-for-a-single-commit-made-on-a-fork-of-a-fork-on-github), I did:

```
git remote add official [URL to original repo]
git checkout -b hotfix-for-feature official/master
git cherry-pick [feature-hash]
git push -u origin hotfix-for-feature
```

and I get:

```
! [rejected]        hotfix-for-feature -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/myusername/repositoryname'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Note how:

1. The branch argument to `git push -u` is just completely ignored and it wants to push to origin/master
2. Neither `origin/hotfix-for-feature` nor `official/hotfix-for-feature` exist remotely.
3. `official/master` is not ahead in any way - I literally just fetched it

If I try `git branch hotfix-for-feature --set-upstream=origin/hotfix-for-feature` I'm told that `git push -u` is the proper way to do this. If I try `git push -u origin/hotfix-for-feature` I get:

```
fatal: You are pushing to remote 'origin/hotfix-for-feature',
which is not the upstream of your current branch 'hotfix-for-feature',
without telling me what to push to update which remote branch.
```

which - apart from being a good example of how not to write your error messages - I don't understand. I specify what to push (current branch) and which remote branch to update.

I find lots of questions about this error, but it is always about some remote branch being ahead and in this case there is no existing remote branch. Also what is the difference between a "pushed branch" and a "remote [branch]"?

Comment: try `git push -u origin hotfix-for-feature:hotfix-for-feature`.

Comment: @dan1st yup, that worked. I wasn´t aware that syntax existed. If you write it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: One more thing, about the difference between "pushed branch" and "remote [branch]": the "pushed branch" is the local branch you're trying to push, while the "remote" one is what exists already on the remote, before push in that particular error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got the following error message:

> ```
> ! [rejected]        hotfix-for-feature -> master (non-fast-forward)
> error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/myusername/repositoryname'
> hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
> hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
> hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
> hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
> ```

The important part of that is

> `hotfix-for-feature -> master`

You are trying to push the local branch `hotfix-for-feature` to the remote branch `master`.

> The branch argument to git push -u is just completely ignored and it wants to push to origin/master

It is not ignored. It pushes the local branch `hotfix-for-feature` to the remote branch `master`.

The [doculentation of `git push`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) meantions the use of a [refspec](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt-ltrefspecgt82308203):

> Specify what destination ref to update with what source object. The format of a  parameter is an optional plus `+`, followed by the source object , followed by a colon `:`, followed by the destination ref .
>
> ...

In the second argument, you can not only specify what (local) branch to push but also what (remote) branch to push to (`git push <remote> <sourcebranch>:<destinationbranch>`).

Knowing this, you can just use `git push -u origin hotfix-for-feature:hotfix-for-feature` for pushing the local branch `hotfix-for-feature` to the remote branch `hotfix-for-feature`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! So since there was already a tracked master branch initially I take it that `git push origin hotfix-for-feature` without the colon was interpreted as `git push origin hotfix-for-feature:master`

Comment: The interesting (odd) thing is that the refspec `b` (vs `b:b`) *normally* **means** `b:b`. However, as the documentation says, "If git push [<repository>] without any <refspec> argument is set to update some ref at the destination with <src> with remote.<repository>.push configuration variable, :<dst> part can be omitted—such a push will update a ref that <src> normally updates without any <refspec> on the command line. Otherwise, missing :<dst> means to update the same ref as the <src>." So this particular repo must have a default push configuration.

Comment: Ultimately, I think the real problem here is that Git had all the defaults wrong for `git push` way back at the start of Git (pre-1.0), and all the patching that's happened since then has just made a giant mess of it. There's now no cure because we're all trained to expect the twistedness. :-)

Comment: Yeah but the colon syntax fixes whatever caused the wrong defaults.

Answer (score 2):

##### TL;DR: Don't create your branch from `official/master`

When you create the branch in the first place, first checkout `official/master` and then do `git checkout -b hotfix-for-feature` without specifying what it should be created from.

You can also do `git checkout -b hotfix-for-feature master`, but explicitly saying `git checkout -b hotfix-for-feature official/master` sets the upstream in a way you don't want.

##### Details

This question surprised me at first, because I routinely do a workflow almost identical to yours, and yet by default `git push -u origin newbranchname` creates branch `newbranchname` on `origin`.

So, I tried to see what is different between your workflow and mine, and I just figured it out.

When you ran:

```
git checkout -b hotfix-for-feature official/master
```

you specifically asked Git to create branch `hotfix-for-feature` to track `official/master`, which means you've already done the `-u` upfront, and set it wrong.

In my workflow, I do this instead:

```
git checkout official/master
git checkout -b hotfix-for-feature
```

which creates a new branch without an upstream.

Then, when I push this branch, using the same syntax as you, the upstream is now set to what you want, on your own fork in your scenario:

```
git push -u origin hotfix-for-feature
```

creates `hotfix-for-feature` on `origin` and sets `origin/hotfix-for-feature` for my local `hotfix-for-feature` branch.

Alternatively, you create the new branch from a local branch, and that won't set the upstream either:

```
git checkout -b hotfix-for-feature master
```

It's just having `official/master` on that last argument that you have to avoid.

Comment: I like that workflow way better indeed - I actually didn´t know `git checkout official/master` is possible. I still prefer the other answer as a marked solution since it fixes the situation I already was in, but for future hotfixes I will absolutely do what you suggest. Thanks for putting the effort in it!

Comment: Yeah, that syntax puts you in a "detached HEAD" state, where you don't normally want to stay, but for this workflow it's exactly what you want since you're about to create a new branch right there and get back to a normal HEAD state one second later.

Answer (score 2):

I personally disagree with the other answers. (I feel it's confusing to track remote branches with a different name, and I dislike checking out local copies of shared branches.) The only tweak I would make in your workflow is at branch creation. I would change this line:

```
git checkout -b hotfix-for-feature official/master
```

to not track the remote branch, like this:

```
git checkout -b hotfix-for-feature official/master --no-track
```

Note, this is what some UI tools do for you when you create a new local branch from a remote branch. For example, in Visual Studio, there is a checkbox for "Track remote branch" which is checked by default, until you change the name of your branch to something else in which case it automatically unchecks that box for you (and adds `--no-track` behind the scenes).

**Tip:** if you ever forget to use `--no-track`, you can always do it after the fact with:

```
git branch --unset-upstream
```

That will fix your current problem as well, after which you can do your initial push with `git push -u` to set your upstream properly.

**Side Note:** I might also tweak that same line in question to use the newer checkout syntax:

```
git switch -c hotfix-for-feature official/master --no-track
```

Comment: Ah, I like `--no-track` too -- I was not aware of that option, but I should have expected it to exist!